# Can the Minor Illusion spell be cast without line of sight?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion, line-of-sight, line-of-effect

Can *minor illusion* be cast without line of sight?

For example, could you cast it behind a wall or through a closed door? Or do you need to see where it’s being manifested? I can't seem to find any threads on this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## You don't have to see the target but you must have a clear path to it

If a spell requires that you must be able to see the target to cast it, it says so. *Minor illusion* does not say so:

> You create a sound or an image of an object within range that lasts for the duration.

All it requires is that the target area be within range.

However, there is a more general restriction that you have to meet that affects all spells: you must have a clear path to the target (from the PHB section on [Targets](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/phb/spellcasting#Targets)):

> To target something, you must have a clear path to it, so it can't be behind total cover.

And, from the description of [Total Cover](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#TotalCover):

> A target with total cover can't be targeted directly by an attack or
> a spell, although some spells can reach such a target by including it
> in an area of effect. A target has total cover if it is completely
> concealed by an obstacle.

So, if the wall or door completely conceals the area you want to target with the spell, you cannot cast *minor illusion*.

Comment: A possible expansion that could be explored: could minor illusion (and similar) be casted via keyhole or some such?

Comment: Another point, could a creature inside a closed off opaque paper tent hear an illusory sound? It would have 'total cover' and by RAW, the illusion of yelling next to the tent could not be heard inside, but an actual yell could be.

Comment: @MarkTO depends on the spell, in the case of minor illusion, the creature isn't a target, the area the illusion is cast on is. So there shouldn't be a direct path issue.